# Как получить минимальную и максимальную цифру из спектра x-y, чтобы сумма единых цифр в полученной цифре был равным z?

Tags: javascript, функции, объекты

```js
let a = {
    x : 10,
    y : 40,
    z : 8,
}
```

Comment: Что значит _сумма единых цифр в полученном цифре..._? Можно немного подробнее?

Comment: например из 10 до 40 минимальная цифра 17(1+7 = 8) а максимальная 35(3+5).

Comment: стало еще менее понятно

Comment: этот маразм для чего ? просто хотелка ?

Comment: Это для того чтобы сделать якобы парольную систему)))

Comment: в смысле генератор паролей ?

Comment: да, из определенного спектра

Comment: есть же специальные прибомбасы - типа шифровальшик паролей

Comment: да, знаю но тут у меня экзамен и мне дали эта упражненияб и оно заканчивается в 18:00 lol helppp!!))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Типа?

```js
const a = {
    x : 10,
    y : 40,
    z : 8,
}

var out = [];

for (let i = a.x; i <= a.y; i++)
{
    let arrayDigits = String(i).split('').map(e => +e);
    
    if (arrayDigits.reduce((a, b) => a + b) === a.z) {
        out[i] = arrayDigits;
    }
}

out = out.filter(e => e);

console.log(out.shift()) // min
console.log(out.pop()) // max
```

Comment: дааa, спасибо огромное :)